# How to pass navigation prop to child component in react navigation v5

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

How to pass navigation prop to child component in react native, I am using react navigation v5, as I want to use navigation.navigate('settings') in the child component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`useNavigation`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/) in your child component.

Example (adapted from the docs):

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

function MyBackButton() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <Button
      title="Go to Settings"
      onPress={() => {
        navigation.navigate('settings');
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works but because of this, I am getting require cycle and My all navigation state are being saved when I Use back button I can see those . How to avoid that I have stack navigator(A) inside there I included a child Component and in that child component I am Navigating to another screen(B).

Comment: @john You would need to restructure your app code. If possible, navigate directly from Stack Navigator (A) to Screen (B) without the "intermediate component"

Comment: Actually the intermediate component (child component) contains list from the redux. The child component is getting list saved in the redux state.

Comment: If your "initial route" depends on that list, the Stack Navigator should have access to that list and define the `initialRouteName` based on that

Comment: ok Thank you I will try to restructure that can you please tell any resource video/documentation where I can understand this nested navigation.

Comment: You can read about [Nesting navigators](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/), but if you have a problem, you can make another question here on SO